# How can I test a trained self-organizing map in R using the kohonen library?

Tags: r, som

I am using the kohonen library in R to train a self-organizing map using some data. I split the data set as 60/40 for training/testing purposes. How can I run the trained model with testing data? I can't find a function in the documentation to do this. How can I review how off the test from the training data is? I am using R 3.3.2 and RStudio 1.0.44.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Comment: I know that SOM is an unsupervised neural network. The predictive mode in that package consists in providing with a test sample of data. Below a snapshot of what I have done so far:
## Training Mode
## Predictive Mode
```{r pred, eval=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
som.prediction <- predict(som.model, newdata = Xtest,
                          trainX = Xtraining, 
                          trainY = data[training, "cluster"])
data[-training, "cluster"] <- factor(som.prediction$prediction)

```

Comment: Below a snapshot of what I have done so far:
## Training Mode  
```{r}
Xtraining <- scale(data[training, c(2:3)])
Xtest <- scale(data[-training, c(2:3)], center = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:center"), scale = attr(Xtraining, "scaled:scale"))

system.time(som.model <- som(Xtraining, grid=somgrid(6, 6, "hexagonal"), rlen=500, alpha=c(0.05,0.01), n.hood = "circular", keep.data = TRUE))
```
## Predictive Mode  
```{r}
som.prediction <- predict(som.model, newdata = Xtest, trainX = Xtraining, 
trainY = data[training, "cluster"])
```

Comment: I have figured this out searching the web. I actually ended up doing the unsupervised branch of the algorithm. I don't need to use test data because is unsupervised modeling. Thanks all for your help!